# Azcopy remove by folder pattern

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have azure blob storage to store files for Azure Data Explorer in partitioned format: `/<company_name>/<year>/<month>/<day>`, so it may be many folders, like:

```
/xyz/2020/01/01
/xyz/2020/02/01
/abc/2020/01/01
/def/2020/02/01
/def/2020/02/02
etc.
```

I need to be able to remove full month or day for all companies. So, for example, if I want to remove month `2020/02` I need to remove folders:

```
/xyz/2020/02/01
/def/2020/02/01
/def/2020/02/02
```

Azcopy utility has command remove with some additional flags --include-pattern, --list-of-files and so on. Is it possible to accomplish my task without explicitly list all paths? 
I.e. I want to have command like:

```
azcopy rm "https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/*/2020/02/*?mysas" --recursive=true
```

Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

For now, it doesn't support wildcard characters (*), you could get it from here:[Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#options).

> --include-path string Include only these paths when removing. This option does not support wildcard characters (*).

You could have a try azure cli command [az storage blob delete-batch](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/cli/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch), it supports the `pattern` to delete blobs recursively.

Comment: azure cli will probably work but I wish to avoid using other than azcopy tools. Trying to perform this task in 2 steps – first list folders which need to be removed and then pass them to --list-of-files parameter. But looks like it is also impossible with list command.